# Is there any way in Batch to add a real time working clock in the top line?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to have a timer in the top line counting down from a minute in seconds, but I don't know if its even possible because I haven't seen a construction like that yet.
Can anyone help me? #shyface

More details: I wanna insert a sand clock in my programm where you have 60 secunds to do a task. So the clock would constantly count down and not implement anything untill you have time.

Here is a picture about what i would like to see working in real time /approximateli/

[image]

Comment: you mean like `timeout /t 60` or `timeout 60` (depending on your OS version) but if you edit your question and be more specific on what you plan on doing, we can probably give you something more concrete/detailed.

Comment: i know the timeout stuff and i use it in my current program as well but its ugly and if i know right, you cant do anything while you're running a timeout /t... @GerhardBarnard

Comment: ok, so please edit your question and show what you want to achieve?

Comment: My crystall ball told me that what the OP really wants is [move the cursor](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7898) to the top line...

Comment: Batch scripts really aren't meant for that kind of application.  Try Powershell or nearly any other scripting language.